# Android Firebase Storage Keep Uploading When Activity Is Destroyed

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-storage

When someone using my android app is uploading a video to Firebase Storage, I want the video to upload even when the activity is destroyed. I tried using asynctask, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the asynctask code:

```
public class UploadAttachment extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        userRef.child("currentSeason").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    final String attachCurrentSeason = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

                    seasonRef.child("id").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            String path = "users/" + mAuth.getUid() + "/" + attachCurrentSeason + "/game" + String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()) - 1);
                            StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference(path);

                            storageReference.putBytes(byteArray);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've read many things saying that Asynctask will still run when the activity is destroyed, but it doesn't work for me. Is it not allowed to use firebase in asynctask?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have [any listeners](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) (completion, success, or failure) attached to the `UploadTask` returned by `putBytes()`.  How have you determined that the upload is starting successfully but not completing?

Comment: @BobSnyder I know it's not working because the firebase storage doesn't show the video as a file

Comment: I'd recommend adding a completion and/or progress listener to `putBytes()` so you at least get some indication that the upload is starting.  It's possible that it's failing immediately because of a security rule or some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

As videos could be very heavy to send, I suggest you to use a Background Service, which you can find informations on the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

You can create it this way: (it is better to define a separate UploadVideoService.java class)

```
public class UploadVideoService extends IntentService {
    public UploadVideoService() {
        super("UploadVideoService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        String path = workIntent.getStringExtra("path");
        StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference(path);
        storageReference.putBytes(workIntent.getByteArrayExtra("data"));
    }
}
```

In your Activity, start the service passing all data to it:

```
//...
userRef.child("currentSeason").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            final String attachCurrentSeason = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            seasonRef.child("id").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String path = "users/" + mAuth.getUid() + "/" + attachCurrentSeason + "/game" + String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()) - 1);

                    // here you call the service, replace Activity with your Activity name
                    Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(Activity.this, UploadVideoService.class);
                    mServiceIntent.putExtra("path", path);
                    mServiceIntent.putExtra("data", byteArray);
                    startService(mServiceIntent);

                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
//...
```

You also have to define the service in your manifest, this way:

```
<service android:name=".UploadVideoService" android:exported="false"/>
```

After the upload is completed you could put a notification in the notification bar to tell the user the job is done, for example.

Comment: Thanks, but it says the byte array is to big to pass and my video is only 4 MB

Comment: If the video is saved in memory then you can pass the Uri to the service as a string

Comment: Thanks i tried this and the files upload when I'm on the app, but when i get off the app while its uploading, it doesn't finish. Also, a side note: I'm not sure if this impacts anything, but right after I start Intent Service, I'm changing activities. I doubt that impacts anything, but just in case. Lastly, is an Intent Service only allowed to start when he app is destroyed? Because I'm starting mine when the app is running

Comment: You can Log what is happening on the IntentService, like checking if the StorageReference is correctly created. An IntentService runs in background, so shouldn't be any difference if the app is opened or closed.
The only thing I could think about is that maybe, as the app gets destroyed, you could lose your reference to Firebase, for this the problems with the upload. So check the StorageReference and look at the logcat to see if there are errors (if you have error in IntentService you couldn't get a crash in visible popup)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I couldn't get an Intent Service to work. However, I did try a regular service and that worked for me.

Comment: @MrAppMachine it will be good for others if you can share how you resolved it with some code sample

Comment: This not good idea. Because internet service will destroy when the last task finished. And you left your old task, which was not completed yet. I offer to use firebase job scheduler.